# How to explain the following javascript snippet result?

Tags: javascript

```
t = 1
c = [1,2,3,4]
1 !== t && 2 !== t || (c[t] = 1)
```

The result output c:[1,1,3,4], and what is the running orders of line3?

Comment: _“and what is the running orders of line3?”_ - for starters, please go read up on [_Operator precedence_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1 !== t` is false, since t equals 1.
So `2 !== t`  does not get evaluated.
It immediately skips to the || ( OR ) clause of
`(c[t]=1)`
Since t = 1, c[t] = 1 sets the second element inside array c, to the value 1.
And then the `()` around it evaluates and returns the result, so c gets logged to the console.
Since we changed the second value inside c to 1, we get [1,1,3,4]

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !(1 !== t && 2 !== t) ) 
    c[t] = 1;
```

which is the same as:

```
if (t === 1 || t === 2)
    c[t] = 1;
```

So basically if t is equal to 1 or equal to 2 then it will set c[t] to 1.

c[t] is c[1] which is the second value in your array. So it used to be 2 and was then set to 1.